# How to move around on a map with mouse and/or keys (RTS-like game)

Tags: java, dictionary, scroll

As the title suggests, I'm making a game where there is a map, the map is of course bigger than could fit on the screen as most RTS games :)
So, any suggestions on how to go about this?
The map is a big JFrame with images drawn on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I changed my map (former JFrame) to a JPanel, adding it to a JScrollPane that is added to the contentPane of the JFrame, see code below:

```
    public Main() //extends JFrame
{
    setDefaultCloseOperation(this.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
    Board b = new Board(db); //extends JPanel
    setSize(400, 200); //size of the JFrame, JPanels size is set in its own constructor
    jsp = new JScrollPane(b); //adding the Board to the JScrollPane
    getContentPane().add(jsp); //adding the JScrollPane to the contentPane
    setVisible(true);
}
```

Now what happens is the Board shows up, with all cells at the right places, I can interact with the map as usual, but no scrolling to be seen anywhere.
Pointers or solution?
<3

Comment: Well, I went mad after beeing unable to figure out how to fix this using JScrollPane, so I made it so whenever I press any of WASD, the map moves accordingly, I simply call every cell of the map and update their setBounds-method. Works extremely well, actually. Havn't tried it on any bigger maps yet, though.

Answer (score 1):

I highly doubt drawing the WHOLE map in memory and just choosing the part to display is scalable. You want to only draw what the user sees instead, in window-coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how big your map is, but you could add the map to a JScrollPane. Hide the vertical/horizontal scrollbars. Then you can position the map by using the viewport of the scrollpane.

Comment: I tried doing this, but It seems you can't add a window to a container... So, yeah, it didn't work :)
How would I do to make my map (currently a JFrame) into someting else that a JScrollPane would accept?

Comment: Well your "map" should NOT be a JFrame. You GUI should NOT extend JFrame. Your "map" should probably be a JPanel which you add to the content pane of a JFrame. Now the JPanel can be added to a scroll pane.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense for the map component to extend JComponent?

Comment: I don't think it makes any difference though.
Just to be sure I tried it and the result is the same.